# Angular 2 - Wrap component children

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to make a reusable tab component and am confused about how to iterate over multiple `ContentChildren` (corrected) within the component to wrap them in html.

I've got a component in my view

```
<demo-tabs>
  <a routerLink="/some/link">Tab 1</a>
  <a routerLink="/some/other/link">Tab 2</a>
  <a routerLink="/some/third/link">Tab 3</a>
</demo-tabs>
```

which I'd like to render like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="/some/link">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/some/other/link">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/some/third/link">Tab 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

It doesn't seem like I can embed content in `ng-content` which is what I tried first, and the following template blows up with `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-tabs',
  template: `<ul class="tabs">
    <li *ngFor="let a of links">
      {{a}}
    </li>
  </ul>`})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren('a') links: TemplateRef<any>; // corrected. I originally had this as @ViewChildren

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, those links are not @ViewChildren() for Tabs component - they are @ContentChildren(), because @ViewChildren() must be declared in the component's template, while @ContentChildren() are coming from an outside declaration - just like you did.

To be able to separate content in such a way you'll need to "mark" all elements with very simple custom structural directive (as follows) so that you could get them as list of separate items in your TabsComponent.

**link.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appLink]'
})
export class AppLinkDirective {
    constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

This is a structural directive that can receive HTML template as a DI injection token. This item's template is what we actually need to be rendered into TabsComponent's template.

Then, let's mark our items:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-demo-tabs>
    <a *appLink routerLink="/some/link">Tab 1</a>
    <a *appLink routerLink="/some/other/link">Tab 2</a>
    <a *appLink routerLink="/some/third/link">Tab 3</a>
</app-demo-tabs>
```

And, finally, render them in the component's template:

**tabs.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, OnInit, QueryList} from '@angular/core';
import {AppLinkDirective} from './link.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo-tabs',
    template: `
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li *ngFor="let link of links">
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="link?.template"></ng-template>
            </li>
        </ul>`
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

    @ContentChildren(AppLinkDirective)
    links: QueryList<AppLinkDirective>;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

And of course you'll need to import this directive in some module so that it could be used in the template.

Comment: Some alternative solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqjlbw?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts but i like your answer

Comment: @yurzui, yes, that's of course possible, and not a bad option at all, but I actually like to put as little stuff in the html as possible - this way it reads more clearly and important things are less hidden under piles of secondary HTML stuff.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I looked at @yurzui's solution too and I see how that works as well, but I agree, this one is clearer (to a noob like myself anyway). Thanks!